# How to Integrate Google Charts in HTML Template?

Tags: django, templates, charts, django-templates, data-visualization

I have a Django Template with a table - result of an iteration.
I am trying to integrate Google Charts in my HTML page for every record, eg. Google Pie Chart.
https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart.html
It works, but the Google chart appears only once irrespective of number of iterations in a loop. And it appears on the same place

[image: This is a Google Chart function draw()]
[image: This is my template file]
[image: My result]

- Is there a way to display different charts for every row in a loop, using Google Charts?
- Is Google Charts the proper solution for such a task? Which simple visualization package could be a solution.
- Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have just got it.
The values in the fuction must be changed in every iteration
[image: result]

This is a template, which is responsible for charting.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      // Load Charts and the corechart and barchart packages.
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});

      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart_Absatz);

      function drawChart_Absatz() {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
        data.addRows([
          ['2016', {{c.abs_2016__sum}}],
          ['2017', {{c.abs_2017__sum}}],
          ['2018', {{c.abs_2018__sum}}],
          ['2019', {{c.abs_2019__sum}}],
        ]);

        var barchart_options = {title:'Absatz, Stueck',
                       width:300,
                       height:200,
                       colors: ['#A52A2A', '#A52A2A', '#A52A2A', '#A52A2A'],
                       legend: 'none'};
        var barchart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('a{{c.tmp_code}}'));
        barchart.draw(data, barchart_options);
      }

</script>
<body>
    <!--Table and divs that hold the pie charts-->
    <table class="columns">
      <tr>
        <td><div id="b{{a.tmp_code}}" style="border: 1px solid #ccc"></div></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Please pay attention that the function must be renamed for every iteration.
This is a newly generated name of the draw() function: a{{c.tmp_code}}. I add a letter "a" in front of the function name, because I have three columns in my table. The draw() function for the second column gets "b", and the third one "c".

And here is the template, which prints the table with embedded charts after every row. I have actually 3 charts after every row, because I have three columns of data.

```
<div class="table-responsive-sm">
<table class="table table-sm" >
<thead>
  <tr class="bg-primary text-white">
    <th>Code</th>
    <th>Bezeichnung</th>
    <th class="bg-dark text-right scope="col">Abs.16</th>
    <th class="bg-dark text-right scope="col">Abs.17</th>
    <th class="bg-dark text-right scope="col">Abs.18</th>
    <th class="bg-dark text-right scope="col">Abs.19</th>

    <th class="text-right scope="col">N.erl.16</th>
    <th class="text-right scope="col">N.erl.17</th>
    <th class="text-right scope="col">N.erl.18</th>
    <th class="text-right scope="col">N.erl.19</th>

    <th class="bg-dark text-right scope="col">DB2 16</th>
    <th class="bg-dark text-right scope="col">DB2 17</th>
    <th class="bg-dark text-right scope="col">DB2 18</th>
    <th class="bg-dark text-right scope="col">DB2 19</th>

  </tr>
</thead>


  {% for c in qset %}

    <tr class="bg-light">
          <td>{{c.tmp_code}}</td>
          <td><a href="./{{c.tmp_code}}">{{c.tmp_descr}}</a></td>
          <td class="bg-secondary text-white text-right">{{c.abs_2016__sum}}</td>
          <td class="bg-secondary text-white text-right">{{c.abs_2017__sum}}</td>
          <td class="bg-secondary text-white text-right">{{c.abs_2018__sum}}</td>
          <td class="bg-secondary text-white text-right">{{c.abs_2019__sum}}</td>

          <td class="text-right">{{c.nerl_2016__sum|floatformat}}</td>
          <td class="text-right">{{c.nerl_2017__sum|floatformat}}</td>
          <td class="text-right">{{c.nerl_2018__sum|floatformat}}</td>
          <td class="text-right">{{c.nerl_2019__sum|floatformat}}</td>

          <td class="bg-secondary text-white text-right">{{c.db2_2016__sum|floatformat}}</td>
          <td class="bg-secondary text-white text-right">{{c.db2_2017__sum|floatformat}}</td>
          <td class="bg-secondary text-white text-right">{{c.db2_2018__sum|floatformat}}</td>
          <td class="bg-secondary text-white text-right">{{c.db2_2019__sum|floatformat}}</td>

    </tr>

   {% block pic1 %}
      {% include 'auswertung/chart1.html'  %}
   {% endblock  %}


  {% endfor %}


  <tr class="bg-primary text-white">
        <td class="text-white"></td>
        <td class="text-white">TOTAL:</td>
        <td class="bg-dark text-right">{{gqset.abs_2016__gsum}}</td>
        <td class="bg-dark text-right">{{gqset.abs_2017__gsum}}</td>
        <td class="bg-dark text-right">{{gqset.abs_2018__gsum}}</td>
        <td class="bg-dark text-right">{{gqset.abs_2019__gsum}}</td>

        <td class="text-right text-white">{{gqset.nerl_2016__gsum|floatformat}}</td>
        <td class="text-right text-white"">{{gqset.nerl_2017__gsum|floatformat}}</td>
        <td class="text-right text-white"">{{gqset.nerl_2018__gsum|floatformat}}</td>
        <td class="text-right text-white"">{{gqset.nerl_2019__gsum|floatformat}}</td>

        <td class="bg-dark text-right">{{gqset.db2_2016__gsum|floatformat}}</td>
        <td class="bg-dark text-right">{{gqset.db2_2017__gsum|floatformat}}</td>
        <td class="bg-dark text-right">{{gqset.db2_2018__gsum|floatformat}}</td>
        <td class="bg-dark text-right">{{gqset.db2_2019__gsum|floatformat}}</td>
    </tr>

    {% block pic2 %}
       {% include 'auswertung/chart1.html'  %}
    {% endblock  %}

</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). In general, code/errors/data in text format >>>> code/errors/data as an image >> nothing. Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.